# Java overloading example with null

Tags: java, overloading

Why primitive 1 consider as object and null as String here

```
public class Sample7 {

    public void getName(String s) {
        System.out.println(s + "string");
    }

    public void getName(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o + "object");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Sample7 s = new Sample7();
        s.getName(null);
        s.getName(1);
    }
}
```

Output:

`nullstring`

`1object`

what is the logic behind the output ??

Comment: What output did *you* expect?

Answer (score 2):

Primite values will be autoboxed to their object representations, so 1 will become `Integer`. But you don't have overloaded method for `Integer`, so it will match the `Object`, because `Integer` is an `Object`, but not a `String`.

`null` case on the other hand is a little bit more interesting. `null` can be any type of object, so in this case the most narrow type is `String`. This is why it matches `String` instead of `Object`.

If you add another method `getName(Integer i)`, the compiler will throw `Amgibigous method call` error when calling `s.getName(null)` because of the same reason - `null` can be both `String` and `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

**Why is null considered a String:**

Any variable/value in Java can be null, which is why you have `nullstring` given that you passed a String to `getName(String s)`.

**Why primitive 1 consider as an object**

`getName(Object o)` Because your method does not have an explicit signature that accepts an Integer, all values in Java is an instance of Object, this is why getName(int) is mapped to getName(Object). 1 is an Object. Java does an implicit type conversion for primitive types [ String, int, double, float, boolean ] declared as Object. which is why you get the value 1.